# what does 'Logged in without disclosing public key - Intrusion?' mean?

Tags: ssh, debian, authentication, gitlab

I have set up a new debian vm and installed gitlab-ce. There is not really much more on the VM...
Right from the beginning, the following msg started to show up in the auth.log:

```
Mon 2015-08-24 21:47:36.154862 CEST [s=a93d5b0787f54cb68c24d8c7c55985a4;i=2c1bc8;b=567468ca921c4b52ba291
    _TRANSPORT=syslog
    _UID=0
    _GID=0
    _BOOT_ID=567468ca921c4b52ba2911c8b97e5f3a
    _MACHINE_ID=b6d23c0be1dbee31de2dd2b1553a4f0c
    _HOSTNAME=kraken
    SYSLOG_FACILITY=4
    PRIORITY=4
    SYSLOG_IDENTIFIER=root
    _COMM=logger
    MESSAGE=ssh/bash[9276]: Logged in without disclosing public key - Intrusion?
    _PID=9283
    _SOURCE_REALTIME_TIMESTAMP=1440445656154862
```

By now it appears a few hundred times a day.

What exactly does it mean? Should I be worried?

---

**update:** the msg does seem to come from sshd

```
   1 23979 23979 23979 ?           -1 Ss       0   4:37 /usr/sbin/sshd -D  
23979  9274  9274  9274 ?           -1 Ss       0   0:00  \_ sshd: root@pts/2    
 9274  9276  9276  9276 pts/2     9276 Ss+      0   0:00      \_ -bash
```

It seems to be triggert at every login from root (at least as well) and then appears in the logs between once and 40 or so times.

```
OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5, OpenSSL 1.0.1k 8 Jan 2015
```

Comment: That isn't a standard error message, and the Internet does not show any instances of the string "Logged in without disclosing public key".  I suspect you're going to have to dig around a bit to discover what's actually writing that.

Comment: @womble Any pointers on how I might find out which process is writing this?

Comment: Look at your bash startup scripts. You likely have something in one of those writing that message.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I completely forgot about that bit... I had some user-logging a while back (authorized keys setting a variable with the name of the keys owner which then got logged). When I set up this vm i copied my bashrc from this older server and never thought about it again. Thanks for pointing me in this direction =) (turns out to be the answer, so if you post it as such I will accept it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The journal entry indicates that, by pid, bash posted the log message, using the `logger` program. This indicates that something in your startup scripts is creating this message.